# is there a scientific way to extract memory from a person brain into video?

Tags: science-based, brain, memory

Just as the title, is there a scientific or possible way to extract past memory from a person brain into some record such as video or visual player ?

I know some theory say that it possible to duplicate neuron pattern to duplicate memory but since human brain have different pattern it is almost impossible, so I want it to turn into real visual to be seen rather than directly into other person.

something similar in [paycheck](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338337/) movie

its not necessary using today's technology, but at least achievable in the future or might be theoretically possible.

Comment: Same comment as to your other question: The answer to this essentially comes down to the tech level - current day tech: no; future - at some point probably yes. If you can clarify what kind of tech/science level answer you want, it should be possible to write an answer that isn't 'that depends'

Comment: The thing is, at present we simply don't know how memories are stored in the brain. We *do* know that they are not stored as video; the brain simply does not have the bandwidth and computing power to store and retrieve video clips. To the best of current understanding, memories are more in the nature of *scripts*, and when retrieved the brain supplies a sort of virtual reality to play back the scripts. (Think how a video game generates the scenes: they are not stored as video or pictures, but rendered on demand by the game engine. A different game engine may render a scene differently.)

Comment: Yes but you can only *play it back* on a brain of the same make and model, as brains from different manufacturers are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Brain scans nowadays can image live the activity of the brain, in particular PET scans.

And those scans can be played back like a clip.

However, as far as I know those scans can image the activation of brain areas, thus you can see them as highly compressed and encoded version of the person's memory.

Comment: PET ([positron emission tomography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography)) scans measure energy usage in the brain and while this correlates to activity in specific area's, it will never be possible to infer (synaptic / electric) activity of individual neurons from them, which would be needed to 'extract memory' in any way.

Comment: @Nicolai, exactly. that's why I state "compressed and encoded"

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to stretch an answer, perhaps you could conduct memory recall through guided lucid dreaming/hypnosis/sleepwalking and a VR simulation of a known environment.

So think about this as forensic scene recreation rather than memory stealing in the vein of "Inception".

Tldr: Occulus/Vive but the visuals are pre-engineered locations, but also with a dynamic asset generation by the dreamer in a pseudo map editor feature.